Displaying Custom Images from Feature Properties Instead of Markers in MapBox iOS
I'm using Mapbox in my iOS application, and I'm currently displaying markers on my Points of Interest (POIs) using the code below. I want to customize these markers to display images from the feature properties instead of a marker icon.
Here's the code I have so far:

Adding a Vector Layer with a Marker to show on POIs:

func addVectorLayer(_ mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
    try? mapProxy?.map?.addImage(UIImage(named: "icon")!, id: "data-image")
    var source = VectorSource(id: "vector-tileset")
    source.url = MapViewLabels.vectorSourceURL

    try? mapboxMap.addSource(source)

    var layer = SymbolLayer(id: "vector-tileset-layer", source: "vector-tileset")
    layer.sourceLayer = "data-bpvgqv"
    layer.iconImage = .constant(.name("data-image"))
    layer.iconAnchor = .constant(.bottom)
    layer.iconOffset = .constant([0, 12])
    try? mapProxy?.map!.addLayer(layer)
}



Tapping on the Layer to Get Feature Properties:

Map()
.onLayerTapGesture(MapViewModel.MapViewLabels.circleLayerId) { feature, context in
    layerTapped(feature, context: context)
}

private func layerTapped(_ feature: QueriedFeature, context: MapContentGestureContext) -> Bool {
    guard let properties = feature.feature.properties else { return false }
    print(properties)
    return true
}


I have URLs to images in the feature properties of my POIs. Instead of displaying the default marker icon, I want to show these images. How can I modify my code to achieve this?
Here’s an example of the feature properties:
{
  "type": "reserve",
  "imageUrl": "https://example.com/image.png",
  "lat": "6.980000019073486",
  "lon": "30.57999992370605",
  "id": "268",
  "pageTitle": "Shambe_National_Park"
}

I have tried to get features by using below code but it gives me empty list.

map?.querySourceFeatures(for: "vector-tileset", options: .init(sourceLayerIds: ["data-bpvgqv"], filter: [:]), completion: { result in
   print(result)
})

Any guidance on how to replace the default marker with the images from the feature properties would be greatly appreciated. I want to show images like reference image.
desired output


Firstly when source loaded data you should caught this event to subscribe on listening event. + Related layer should display invisible markers.

mapboxMapView.mapboxMap.onSourceDataLoaded.observe { [weak self] sourceData in

        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)


Then you should fetch all loaded features for source

...
let options = SourceQueryOptions(sourceLayerIds: <layerIds>, filter: true)
guard let queriedFeatures = try? await mapView.mapboxMap.asyncQuerySourceFeatures(
                for: <sourceId>,
                options: options
            ) else {
                continue
            }
...


Then you should get image url from all queriedFeatures and preload all images by url and save in dict [String: UIImage] Url: Downloaded Image

Then you should create layout by CALayer(in CALayer and not UIView for example because you can do screenshot in background if you use UIView and you probabbly don't want block UI do it in the main thread) and paste image and make screenShot image and save result into mapbox. You should do it for each downloaded image.

Then you should create another one source and layer to display the new prepared data.


try? self.mapView.mapboxMap.addImage(<image>, id: <imageName(thisImage then you should use in the layer configuration)>)

It is appropriate plan what you need to do. The real implementation pretty much heavy.
If something not clear ask, will try to help.
